# Retrieve keys from Key vault in Console application with out saving Azure AppID and secret in the code

Tags: c#, .net, azure-keyvault

I want to implement key vault set up for my .Net console application. So that I can retrieve the keys from Key vault store.

Note:- I have already implemented retrieving keys from key vault using Azure App ID and Secret. Here we have to store App ID and secret in the application web.config file. But Cred Scan tool is not allowing to store them in the Application configuration pages. Causing unable to check in the solution to GIT repositories.

Please suggest any alternatives.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any suggestions from Cred scan tool for where they should be stored? You can use some other file instead of config file. Also can think of putting it in database if you have database as part of the application

Comment: You could put them in web.config then delete the actual content lines from the file. Then if the next person doesn't spontaneously add those keys, and some relevant values, the defaults will be used, which will be blank and won't achieve anything.   Cred Scan is trying to stop you uploading precious secrets to GitHub, so just don't upload them :)

Comment: Where are you gonna deploy your console app ? azure VM ? Webjobs ?